# Hot drink shaker

Tags: coffee, cocktails

I make hot coffee drinks at home (espresso, 1/2&1/2, sugar).  I'd like to shake them rather than stir. Is there such a thing as a shaker which can endure the pressure of a shaken hot drink?  I imagine something like the bomb calorimeters we used in college - an insulated metal container with a tightly threaded lid.  Preferably for a single serving.  Does any such thing exist?

Now... why do I do this?  I've had limited success with screw top glass jars.  Shaking the coffee and 1/2&1/2 introduces a lot of air into the drink giving it a milk-shake consistency.  I can do with with only 15ml of milk rather than the Starbucks style "all milk, shot of coffee".  A shaken hot coffee with milk produces a thick beverage that's 95% coffee and only a dash of milk.

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure about an appropriate container for shaking, because as you noticed shaking heats the air in the container which in turn expands, leading to all kinds of pressure problems.

My alternative suggestion: 
Have you considered an immersion blender? Some of these come with metal disks that can be substituted for the cutting blades. With sufficient power, you can even whip very cold low / non fat milk into whipped cream -like consitency. Should work for thickening your coffe as well.

---

(The process of whipping milk is described for example [here](http://www.sensorynutrition.com/2013/02/immersion-blender-created-milk-based-whip/).)

Comment: The pressure thing isn't all that bad - you should be able to shake a little, crack it open to vent, maybe repeat once or twice, then be fine.

Comment: @Jefromi Yes. but it's cumbersome, will leak at least a small bit when opening etc....

Comment: agreed; had similar issues when i worked as a bartender; ends up making a mess.  90% of hot drinks are stir only for this reason.

Alternative; you could use a mixer if wanted "froth"; for home use a Nutri Bullet or vitamixer would work; pending budget.  Be sure whatever you use is BPO free; don't want "nasties" leeching into the hot liquid.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this finally! A mason jar with a screw on lid does the trick nicely. I expect the glass will break eventually, but they're cheap and easily replaceable.

Comment: until you break the glass while shaking the content ... hot drinks+glass shards = not fun.

Comment: @Max I don't understand the concern over the glass breaking, I have hot liquid in my glass coffee pot each morning. There's nothing inherent to shaking a drink that would lead to the glass breaking. My problem with using mason jars for this is the hot liquid can spurt out when unscrewing the top and burn hands.

Comment: I can confirm there's no spray when opening the lid. Also, in my experience mixing things in mason jars for years... they will crack but won't explode shards everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A small Thermos should work. They make single serving sizes and they have screw on lids. Something like this [Thermos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JFB2RA6)